# Had better not(?)

Tags: conditionals

My friend learns English: He said something like, “You had better not to take these pills a lot”.

It sounded off to me. Could you help me explain to him why/what he tried to do?

Comment: [My friend is learning English.] You had better cannot be followed by "to".

Comment: Apart from that unwanted infinitive marker ***to***, the overall construction isn't particularly idiomatic. Natural alternatives include *You'd better not **take a lot of** these pills* - or even more idiomatically, *You'd better not **take too many** of these pills* and *You'd better not take these pills **too often***.

Comment: It is idiomatic to say: You better not do x a lot or too much.

Comment: Ah. No this really helps. I think I wanted to tell him about this concept of speaking idiomatically; And infinitive markers.